# Xamarin Forms Cell Manipulation RTL

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I've built a list view using the following XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="_lstMenu" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What I'm trying to do is when the language is switched to Arabic is making the whole user experience right-to-left oriented. In order to do that I'm using the RotateYTo(180) method.

```
protected override void rotateElementsY(int rotationY)
{
    base.rotateElementsY(rotationY);

    foreach (View sub in subviews())
    {
        sub.RotateYTo(rotationY);
    }
}

private View[] subviews()
{
    View[] _subs = new View[] {
        imgUser, lblGreetings, lblUserName, lstMenu, stkBottom};
    return _subs;
}
```

It is working well so far, except for the ImageCell as I'm only able to display it in left-to-right direction only, and unable to rotate any of the Cell's childs (label, image).

PS: I also tried to write the cell's Arabic text in reverse after mirroring the list view, but it still doesn't look appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to ganchito55 for inspiring me to the answer I needed. I pretty much used his idea of making RTL, but with the capacity of also changing to LTR when needed.

```
<ListView x:Name="_lstMenu" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" IsVisible="{Binding isEnglish}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="{Binding alignment}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding IconSource}" IsVisible="{Binding isArabic}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As you can see I've added another image to the item template, and properties to the listed item object to decide to display which image and alignment to use each time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution for RTL languages is that you create a custom cell when you have the image on the right and then the label with right alignment, for example:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="_lstMenu"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I hope this can help you.